# how to fix Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';'

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have used my code but its false Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF shop\wrapper-start.php on line 39
this my code, can help me?

```
<?php
switch( $template ) {
        case 'twentythirteen' :
            echo '<div id="primary" class="site-content"><div id="content" role="main" class="entry-content twentythirteen">';
            break;
        default :
            echo '<div class="content-container">';
            echo '<div class="bg-left">';
            echo the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-banner'));
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="content-right">';
            echo '<div class="menu-wrapper">';               
            echo '<div class="menu-wrapper-inner">';    
            echo wp_nav_menu();
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="content-inner">';
            echo '<div class="container-inner">';       
            echo if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            echo the_content();         
            echo endwhile else;
            echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';                   
            echo endif;              
            echo '</div>';      
            echo '</div>';      
            echo '</div>';      
            echo '<div class="sidebar">';       
            echo get_sidebar();         
            echo '</div>';  
            echo get_footer();      

            break;
    }
```

Comment: You've listed two different errors, one of which appears on a line beyond the end of this code. What are you asking?

Comment: I guess it's the row: echo if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); but you should consider getting a better IDE for development if your current one doesn't point that out for you. I do recommend NetBeans but there are a lot of options out there.

Comment: echo if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
echo the_content();         
echo endwhile else;

Rewrite this. I haven't tried, but I doubt that it works.

Comment: i have tried but still not working. any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch( $template ) {
    case 'twentythirteen' :
        echo '<div id="primary" class="site-content"><div id="content" role="main" class="entry-content twentythirteen">';
        break;
    default :
        echo '<div class="content-container">';
        echo '<div class="bg-left">';
        echo the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-banner'));
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="content-right">';
        echo '<div class="menu-wrapper">';               
        echo '<div class="menu-wrapper-inner">';    
        echo wp_nav_menu();
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="content-inner">';
        echo '<div class="container-inner">';       
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            echo the_content();         
         endwhile; 
         else:
            echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';                   
        endif;              
        echo '</div>';      
        echo '</div>';      
        echo '</div>';      
        echo '<div class="sidebar">';       
        echo get_sidebar();         
        echo '</div>';  
        echo get_footer();      

        break;
}
```

Try this code. Error was because, you have written echo on if & while condition. You need not echo conditions. 
Hope this helps.